# How to delete subfolder recursively

Tags: python

I have the following problem:

I would like to delete subdirectories and files recursively. I have the follow:

200 Subdirectories. Each of them has this structure:

```
             case
A0    A1   A2---------A100
```

Each Folder of this 100 has 3 sub-folders. 2 of them should be kept. The other one has a subdir and multiple files. I want just to keep one of the files and also want to keep the subfolder

I hope this picture will help to show what i want really to do. I have a folder let's say case. This folder has 100 subdirectories. For example for the 0 Folder, i want to keep all about B and D. However in the Folder C want just to keep K and the file l.gz. This process should run for all the 100 Folders A0-A100.

Comment: You can use `os.walk` to navigate the file structure and decide which ones to keep.

Comment: What have you tried? While some folks on Stack Overflow may answer regardless, you're likely to get more (and more helpful) answers if you've already made an attempt to solve your problem and are asking about the issues you ran into.

Comment: thank you for the help. Still trying to write some lines to get the job done. I#m new in writing scripts with python. I like it. I'm trying to collect the informations then i will write some lines

Comment: basically, i have in my case more then 100 Subfolders. Each of them has 3 subfolders. (S1, S2 and S3). I want to keep S1 S2 with the whole content. But in S3 i want to keep all the subfolders and  delete alle the files except Gmean.gz. I know i have to use at least os.walk but how ? BTW all the files in the subfolder S3 have the same extension

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
os.system ('rm -r {}'.format(yourfolderName))
```

The folder name you put here will delete folder recursively.